# Accessing ActionBar Action Buttons container

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to customize the Buttons on the ActionBar and I am using the Support Library to have ActionBar since Api 7.

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/453x100q90/539/Jc9LNz.png

I know how to access buttons 1, 2, 3 to customize it's view, but I do not know how to access the overflow item (number 4). That's why I think it would be better to access directly to the Container instead of one by one buttons. I suppose the container is a Linear Layout or similar. Is there any way to access it to set it's height and margins? I would like the buttons to have a small margin with the top and the same at the right.

Btw, where can I browse the default ActionBar layout xml, or code? With that I would be able to perform the action.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by accessing buttons?

Comment: I meant accessing button's Views. I can customize the button's view (i.e. set background) but I would like to customize the wrapper.